# Using Variable in a path Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord

`const dispatcher = connection.playFile('C:/Users/Discord/Desktop/${myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]}');`

I need the string in the `connection.playFile` function to be able to take a value from an array so that I can pass in filenames.

Comment: If an answer has helped you, please consider 'accepting' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

Use backticks ([template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) instead of single quotes `'`.

You will then be able to access variables within `${...}`

```
const dispatcher = connection.playFile(`C:/Users/Discord/Desktop/${myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]})`
```